# nutch redirection handling issue

Tags: nutch

I am bit new to nutch . Thing is I am crawling a url which redirects to another url .Now when analysing my crawl results I get content of first url along with status code : temp redirected to (second url name) . Now my question is that why I am not getting content and details of that second url .Is that redirected url getting crawled or not? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Again, in the omnipotent [nutch-default.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/conf/nutch-default.xml?view=markup), there is an attribute that controls the way how Nutch handles redirection.

```
<property>
  <name>http.redirect.max</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>The maximum number of redirects the fetcher will follow when
  trying to fetch a page. If set to negative or 0, fetcher won't immediately
  follow redirected URLs, instead it will record them for later fetching.
  </description>
</property>
```

As the description has mentioned, `fetcher won't immediately follow redirected URLs and record them for later fetching`. I still have not figured out how to force the URLs in **`db_redir_temp`** to be fetched. However, if you change the configuration right at the beginning, I assume your probably might go away.

Answer (score 0):

In Nutch2.3.1, I tried to set following property in my nutch-site.xml and it helped me to fetch redirected URL in the next attempt. It may be helpful to someone trying on Nutch 2.3.1.

```
<property>
      <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
      <value>0</value>
      <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days).
      </description>
  </property>
```

Comment: basically I made the wait period value as 0 so that url is available for refetch.

Answer (score 0):

In Nutch 2.3.1 there's a method called getProtocolOutput in the class

> org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase

in this method there's a calling to another method

```
Response response = getResponse(u, page, false); (Line 250)
```

Change the false To true in the previous code

As this flag refer to followRedirects

Then recompile the nutch classes , and follow redirect will work correctly :)